# Aurelia - custom events: trigger or delegate?

Tags: javascript, aurelia, dom-events

In Aurelia, binding events to methods is done either via `trigger` or `delegate`. There's quite a good explanation in the docs on which one to use:
http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/binding/latest/binding-delegate-vs-trigger/1

However, the docs does not mention [`CustomEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent). What is the guidelines in case of `CustomEvent`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit complicated, because `CustomEvent` is quite customizable and can be sent at any point of time.

Aurelia docs says `delegate` is preferred. However, the implementation of `delegate` relies on a global event handler of `<body>` element, so cannot be used always. An element dispatching an event, which then bubbles up to `<body>`, to the root of all visibles in the DOM. So in order to make `delegate` work:

1. Bubbling has to be enabled on the `CustomEvent`
2. the sender element (which the `dispatchEvent` is being called on) should be attached to the DOM-tree. So that the event actually reaches the `<body>` while bubbling.

Point 1. is just a matter of settings, so let's see 2. This depends on if the event is being dispatched *before* or *after* the viewmodel is being attached to the DOM (before `attached()` callback). If *before*, then `delegate` won't work, use `trigger`. Otherwise use `delegate`.

Happens *before* attaching to DOM → use `trigger`:

- constructor
- router callbacks: `canActivate()`, `activate()`
- initial bindig callbacks: `bind()`, changed callbacks for bindables, `xxxChanged()`

Happens certainly *after* attached → use `delegate`: basically built-in user-based DOM-events (click, select, change, etc.). Reason: because the user can only interact with our viewmodel, if it is already in the DOM.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry I cannot comment, balazska's answer is great but it assumes you understand clearly how everything in event works. To simplify his version:

If you listen to custom event on something like this:

```
<div repeat.for='items of my_1000_items_collection' custom-event.trigger='doIt()'></div>
```

You are registering 1000 listener entries. In this case, better use delegate and adjust code if needed, it may increase the performance of your application.

You can also use `capture`, which is undocumented at the moment.(on it's way to release) [Capture Event](https://github.com/aurelia/binding/pull/530)

```
<div repeat.for='items of my_1000_items_collection' custom-event.capture='doIt()'></div>
```

Comment: That is true, but if `custom-event` is being sent "early" (constructor, bind, activate, etc.), then`trigger` is the only way to capture that event.

Comment: I haven't run into situation where events are needed during component setup phase but that will be useful approach.

Comment: I just did, that's why I've come up with the problem in the first place. Speaking of concretions: `initialized` event is being sent from `bind()` method, after the bound data was transformed.